# Limiting Log Size in Apache Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I have an Apache Tomcat 7.0 install (Windows machine). I'm not fluent in managing it. Our /logs folder keeps growing. **How can I limit the file size of this directory / of the logs?**

I already added a log4j.properties file to /lib (steps 1 and 2) as mentioned on the [Tomcat 6.0 Logging page](http://yzb.hit.edu.cn/docs/logging.html)  but this seems to be ineffective.

I'm **looking for a configuration solution to this,** not a crazy script or scheduled task that will delete log files periodically.

Comment: are you sure you tried all the six steps mentioned in that link?

Comment: I only tried steps 1 and 2. I thought log4j configuration works without rebuilding source (and I don't have the source anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j is not easy to set up because it requires the Tomcat source. JULI doesn't have configuration to control log file size. Since the log files are already rotating (by default), just run a shell script or batch file periodically to delete all the log files.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any source to use Log4J. You just download all the jar files directly from Apache, put them in your lib and bin folders accordingly and you're ready to go. The most difficult part is creating a log4j.properties file, but there are plenty of templates out there you can just copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/). It is not entirely what you want (to rotate by size), but I find logs sorted by time to be much more easy to process and search.

For example you can configure your Tomcat/Apache to rotate logs each day and delete/zip those older than week. Or rotate by hour and delete/archive those older that few days, etc.

Comment: I'd prefer the simpler approach of just using Scheduled Tasks to periodically delete the logs, since they're already rotating.